# create new array of fileinfo without setting any index or object on it

Tags: c#, .net

there is this "if" in my c# code that makes me to create an empty FileInfo in my code, so i can fill  it after the "if"

I have tried this code, but it doesnt work, it seems there is something to be done with FileInfo array
    `FileInfo[] FileCheck = new FileInfo[]();
    if (chbSubFolder.Checked == false)
        FileCheck = Dir.GetFiles(string.Format("*.{0}", extention));
    else
        FileCheck = Dir.GetFiles(string.Format("*.{0}", extention), SearchOption.AllDirectories);`

Comment: Directory.GetFiles returns a string[].

Answer (score 4):

Either specify the size of the array:

```
FileInfo[] FileCheck = new FileInfo[5];
```

Or initialize it to an empty array:

```
FileInfo[] FileCheck = new FileInfo[]{};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
FileInfo[] FileCheck;
if (chbSubFolder.Checked == false)
    FileCheck = Dir.GetFiles(string.Format("*.{0}", extention));
else
    FileCheck = Dir.GetFiles(string.Format("*.{0}", extention), SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

You're assigning it in either case, so you don't have to init it.

Answer (score 0):

If `Directory.GetFiles` returns a `string[]`

```
FileInfo[] FileCheck = default(FileInfo[]);
if (chbSubFolder.Checked == false)
    FileCheck = Dir.GetFiles(string.Format("*.{0}", extention));
else
    FileCheck = Dir.GetFiles(string.Format("*.{0}", extention), SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```